# In AngularJS, how do I track a watcher to a view and delete them automatcally as the view is removed or replaced?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I’m new to AngularJS (a few days) so I’m having a bit of trouble with it.**

I’m trying to create an equivalent to `ng-bind-html`, but more permissive.
I’ve searched all over and managed to get it to accomplish mostly everything I need.
In short I want to do this
`<div template-compile-unsafe="code"></div>`
Where `code` is `$scope.code`.  As the value of `$scope.code` is modified it is recompiled into HTML and inserted into the DIV tag.  I’ve even managed to get it to evaluate Angular expressions and create code that even has binding.
For example set `$scope.code` this String
`"<input type='text' ng-model='txtInput'><br>{{txtInput}}"`
and you get what is expected.
But the problem is that when I change the code and it recompiles, it doesn’t delete the old watchers, but keeps adding more.  Examine `$scope.$$watchers` to see that.

**To solve this I’ve tried the following:**
- Storing the return function for `$scope.$watch(…)`, but it doesn’t seem to work when I accumulate more functions.

- I’ve tried adding identifying variables in `$scope.$$watchers[n]` object to keep track of the particular watcher, but they’re quickly purged every time a new watcher is added to this array.

- So far I haven’t seen anyway way to automatically unbind a watcher if the view is removed or replaced.  I’ve looked into `$destroy` I can’t seem to make that work unless I destroy the `$scope`, but that doesn’t help because I only need particular watchers removed.

- I’ve tried `element.on(“$destroy”, …)`

- I can’t use `$routeProvider` because I need to change only specific areas in the DOM often independent of each other.  That and I can’t have the URL suddenly keep changing if the user is presses a key when typing.

- And I’ve even tried ignoring the problem, but as watchers accumulate the `$scope.$watch(…)` calls progressively increase to accomplish the same model-view updating.  When I use this in larger and more complex applications or start nesting `<div template-compile-unsafe="code"></div>` the web app becomes noticeably slower in a very short period of time.

The whole point of this is to dynamically load robust templates with Angular expressions and directives to easily swap out tiny to large portions of a site.

**See what I have so far [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bennyhoward/tvnzt2aL) please feel free to edit.  In fact I encourage it.**

Comment: "The whole point of this is to dynamically load robust templates with Angular expressions and directives to easily swap out tiny to large portions of a site." => you jnow that angular has its own robust template mechanims ? Why don't you just use it ?

Comment: If you mean something like ng-bind-html or directives with templates being set to something I've tried it, but it doesn't do what I want.  For example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bennyhoward/69w1trn8) is the same JSFiddle I posted before, but using ng-bind-html with $sceProvider.enabled(false).  As you can see it doesn't evaluate angular expressions.  My previous example does and it does it dynamically, but it doesn't remove the watchers automatically when html is changed.